# How to create async call with jquery with android using phonegap?

Tags: android, jquery, asynchronous, cordova

I have seen background service in phonegap and integrated successfully but, I need to make an ajax call to get the data from server.This call need to be happen in background process without disturbing the UI. I am unable to do this using this plugin.
And my code look like,

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://example.com/xxx",
   dataType: "xml",
   async:true,
   success: function (data) {
                 var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                 var xmlString = serializer.serializeToString(data);
                 var finalxml= xmlString.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace('<br/>','\n');
                 window.localStorage.setItem("xml_Questions",finalxml);

                 }
      });
```

This ajax call has to be done with async(background) call while user doing something..
But user is not able to do anything until get the response.So I have followed Background service plugin for phonegap, but I am not able to implement this method with that plugin.
Can we do this?
Can anybody help me?

Thank you in adv...

Answer (score 0):

Your $.ajax code looks right to me, so it shouldn't block the app behavior.

I don't completely understand your question... user shoudn't be allowed to do anything until the localstorage.setitem is set? If this is right, you could use jquery to enable some kind of "NEXT" button after the setItem instruction, so the user won't be able to move on until the async call is done.

Comment: No, user has to do anything this call should work in background.